# Xcode .m vs. .mm

Tags: xcode

In the zxing iphone project the readme states:

> - It can happen that when trying to build your own project with
>     ZXingWidgetController you get linker
>     errors like "undefined reference to".
>     If this error looks like a c++
>     undefined reference, then renaming
>     main.m into main.mm (Objective-C++
>     source suffix) may fix the problem

It did indeed. But I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

.mm extension stands for Objective-C++, when compiler can process C++ classes.
But when using .m extension it will be able to compile only C code, without C++ classes.

Answer (score 7):

Both `.m` and `.mm` are class file extensions of source code for Mac-based applications. `.m` files can contain both *Objective-C* and *Objective-C++* classes. To avoid conflicts between the two in mixed-use scenarios there's the convention to rename all *Objective-C++* class files to `.mm`. This helps compilers to distinguish.

So in a project which uses both *Objective-C* and *Objective-C++* you will see:

- `.m` files containing *Objective-C*
- `.mm` files containing *Objective-C++*

Comment: so usually one should just use .m then?