# Undefined symbols for armv7 on iOS 5: _aes_icm_advance_ismacryp

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xcodebuild, armv7

I have one app I built with Xcode 4.2 for iOS 4.3, and I want to build it on Xcode 4.2 + iOS 5 beta 7 for Snow Leopard but I get the error below:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7
"_aes_icm_advance_ismacryp", referenced from:
```

I have one class contain the method `aes_icm_advance_ismacryp`. The architecture setting on iOS 4.3 was i386 so I tried to change it to i386 but Xcode won't let me.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You are missing the ISMACryp library.

Answer (score 0):

What do your build settings display for their architectures? 
It should look something like this

(My screenshot is from Xcode 5 so it will not be exact): 
[image: SCREENSHOT]

If you have nested project dependencies, you'll have to check those targets as well.