# Flurry ads library undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Tags: flurry, armv7

I would like to use Flurry ads in my upcoming application. I have already installed the analytics package and love how easy it is to track users and events.

However, I am having an error implementing ads with the new 4.0.1 SDK that I have found no answers to. Every time I try to build my Xcode 4.2 project I get this error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer init] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePreloadDidFinish:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer stopMovie] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer init] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePreloadDidFinish:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clearly something has gone wrong with my FlurryAds.a library. I have tried several times to follow the Flurry advertising instructions to the letter but despite my best efforts I still have this error. My library is linked correctly within build phases and I have done my best to implement the fixes described here [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) but to no avail.

Any ideas? Thank you so so much for your help.

Comment: Try adding the Media Player Framework to your project.

Answer (score 5):

I've the same error with XCode 5.1

I've resolve this to link `MediaPlayer.framework` and `AdSupport.framework` in the project.