# GData iPhone Archive Error

Tags: ios, xcode, gdata

Following the instructions here: http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

I added GData to my iOS 5 project.  When it's time to archive the project I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryYouTubeVideo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
      objc-class-ref in ListController.o
      objc-class-ref in ShareController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked the build settings for the GData.xcodeproj -> GDataTouchStaticLib, and this is what I set them to as seen by this pic: )
[image]

Any help is appreciated, to help get my project archived.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't linked the libraries properly. Make sure you follow the directions carefully when it comes to adding the library paths.  See [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) for more information.

Comment: I assumed the link that I followed was the correct way to link the GData libraries to an xcode project.  I removed the static library from the build phases.  Dragged the GData Sources folder in the project.  Then added the missing .h and .m files the project was complaining about into the compile sources section.  Still the same error.  I also wanted to note, that adding the files as I tried to add them causes build errors when attempting to compile to the simulator.  Relinking the static library fixes that.

Comment: so are you still having issues or did this answer fix it?