# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, armv7, benchmarking

I am stuck into errors when using [codeTimestamp](http://eng.pulse.me/line-by-line-speed-analysis-for-ios-apps/) classes to checkout speed of my code.
But these classes are working on any other project. I don't know what happen to this.
Errors are:
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__Z25LogTimestampChunkInMethodPKciaa", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView renderFrameQCAR] in EAGLView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Thanks in advance for help, have a great day.

Comment: have you added .m files in compiled resource

Comment: How to add .m file in compiled resource?

Comment: @AyazAlavi: When you run the application .m files are automatically added to the compiled sources. But while you adding some external file to the project  it can be missed. Thats why you can add .m files manually by from selecting project icon -> build phases.

Comment: @VXtreme: I Added those files in compiled resource but still showing same errors.

Comment: have you selected the copy option while adding those files into your project.check :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Yes i selected copy option while on dragging to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You know you have to set the -fno-obj-arc flag on that file, right?
- Look in your EAGLView source file, and find where you use LogTimestampStartChunk. Is that the only file you added LogTimestampStartChunk to? If so then for whatever reason, the CodeTimeStamp.o is not being added to your Target. If you do have the LogTimestampStartChunk used in other files, comment it out of EAGLView and see if you can get it to build.

Ultimately, if you cannot use this macro in even one file and get the project to build, then you never included the CodeTimeStamp.o file. If you can get it to build otherwise, then its something about EAGLView.