# xcode, launching on simulator is ok but cannot archive

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, homebrew, .a

I am new to Xcode.

I am adding some features on the old(iOS 3.2) xcode game project. This code never touched for more than a year until I touched.
It worked fine until I tried to make an .iap file. it ran ok and all my changes didn't make any error.
So I changed target device from iPhone 6.0 Simulator -> iOS Device, and tried archive. Unfortunately it generated bunch of errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file lib/libegn_neutron_http_Release_iphoneos.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): lib/libegn_neutron_http_Release_iphoneos.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_EGN_setPollingInMenu", referenced from:
      ExitGamesCreateSession(sLibraryData*) in exitgames.o
  "_EGN_Neutron_New", referenced from:
      ExitGamesInit(sLibraryData*) in exitgames.o
  "_EGN_setServerUrl", referenced from:
      ExitGamesCreateSession(sLibraryData*) in exitgames.o
```

......similar 34 errors continued

```
  "_EGN_NeutronCls_Release", referenced from:
      ExitGamesShutDown(sLibraryData*) in exitgames.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This project uses some "exitgames" library which supports social features. 
Also this project have some wrapping part of "Brew" c++ codes.
I don't know which part has the problem. tried to figure out and searched a whole day but still couldn't get a clue.

Can anybody give me an advice?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running lipo -info exitgames.a from the command line, it should tell you what architectures the framework is made to support.

Comment: was nice advice. it was for v6. I removed all these exit games libraries and it ran ok..