# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: duplicate files

Tags: ios, xcode

I received this error when I imported the DropboxSDK:

[image]

Is is very strange, but I noticed that both the dropbox sdk header folder and one of the .h files I am using in another part of my app have this file: Base64Transcoder

I tried changing my other one to Base64Transcoder2, but the error persists. What might the solution be to this problem?

Comment: Did you clean and then rebuild?  Did you change all references to Base64Transcoder to Base64Transcoder2?  Can you simply not include one of the .o file with the conflicting symbols?

Comment: I didn't clean, i'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add that .m class file to Project->Target ->Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

EDIT:

This is a good answer. [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: Have you tried all three solutions provided in the link above?

Comment: Yes, the errors vanish if I remove also 1 other file named  NSData+Base64Additions.m, but at that point my SMTP email don't work any more

Comment: For some reason if I add the old dropbox sdk v 1.2.2, everything works fine, but if I use the latest 1.3.3, with the exact same files, there is the error. I noticed that the error vanishes if I remove a part of the code including size_t outBufferEstLength = EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize([self length]) + 1;