# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 after adding .a file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to build a small app using a *.a, *.h file I received from a certain vendor. 
this is the first time I'm adding external files to a project.

I added the files and I am getting these errors.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>
> "_vDSP_fft_zropD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)
>       "_vDSP_vclrD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)     "_vDSP_vdbconD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)
>       "_vDSP_vmulD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)    "_vDSP_hamm_windowD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_init in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)    "_vDSP_zaspecD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hrMonitor.o)   "_EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification", referenced from:
>         -[HRMonitor startup] in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hrMonitor.o)   "_vDSP_create_fftsetupD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_init in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)   "_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
>         -[HRMonitor startup] in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hrMonitor.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hrMonitor.o)    "_vDSP_ctozD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)    "_vDSP_maxmgvD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_estimation in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)    "_vDSP_destroy_fftsetupD", referenced from:
>         _fft_hr_free in libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a(hr_calc.o)   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So far I've tried: (mentioned in other posts)

1. I've made sure the the *.a file is included in the *Link Binary With Library* .
2. Tried to change C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library to Compiler Default.

More info:

1. The files are in the project folder.
2. I'm using an iPhone 4S v.6.1.3 and the project's deployment target is iOS 6.1.

Comment: Is the .a file you are linking to libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a? If so, it looks like there's another lib it needs before it (maybe the Accelerate.framework)... Also try link the ExternalAccessory.framework

Comment: @jjv360 you just saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Just for future I got the `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:` error. It was fixed by adding `ExternalAccessory.framework` to `Targets > myApp > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check lib path is correct in framework search path / library search path
2. check other linker flags needed for your lib source

[Please refer this Answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429568/1357774)