# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with CGContext

Tags: ios, xcode, cgcontext, armv7

This error is driving me crazy, any idea?

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

```
"_CGContextConcatCTM", referenced from:
  -[PopoViewController onClick:] in PopoViewController.o
"_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
  -[PopoViewController onClick:] in PopoViewController.o
"_CGContextSaveGState", referenced from:
  -[PopoViewController onClick:] in PopoViewController.o
"_CGContextRestoreGState", referenced from:
  -[PopoViewController onClick:] in PopoViewController.o
```

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

The binary with libraries are linked.
The library search path is correct.

Thanks

Comment: I think this will help you.. 
see this question  [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 0):

Link your application with CoreGraphics.framework for iPhoneOS architecture.