# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 - Static Library

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, armv7

I'm from Argentina and my English is very limited. Sorry about that.

I tell them about my problem:

I downloaded the SDK for iOS Hikvision cameras from this link: http://www.hikvision.com/en/download_more.asp?id=1207

This includes static library file called "libPlayCtrl.a" and two headers "ApplePlayM4.h" & "PlayM4.h"

The problem is that to include the library in my project, I get the error:

"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"

I followed the suggestions in this link: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) and I could not compile the project in any way.

Has anyone worked with this program and can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Which symbols is it complaining about?

Comment: Sorry. The code above comment was from a test I did. The correct error message is as follows (I copy only a part, will not let me copy it integer):

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_glEnableClientState", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView drawFrame:frameWidth:frameHeight:] in libPlayCtrl.a(EAGLView.o)
  "_glEnable", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView drawFrame:frameWidth:frameHeight:] in libPlayCtrl.a(EAGLView.o)
  "_glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView createFramebuffer] in libPlayCtrl.a(EAGLView.o)

Comment: It seems that your library wants to link to OpenGL and that you have not included OpenGL libraries in the link phase of your build.

Comment: @FernandoJuarez hi. did you use hikvision skd ? was it work fine ? can you please provide me hint that how i can use hikvision lib ?

Comment: @FernandoJuarez i want to create demo for hikvision sdk but where can i start i don't know so if you can help me than i will be do it

Answer (score 1):

This question was posted awhile ago. I recently attempted to integrate the HikVision iOS Player SDK for a project as well. I ran into similar errors, symbols not defined for armv7 architecture, as well as a few others. The HikVision documentation for the sdk does not give you the dependent libraries for clean and easy integration. I have included the following libraries, CoreAudio, CoreVideo, AudioToolbox, and OpenAL, as well as the libstdc++.6.0.0.dylib. With all these included in a test project within my environment using  XCode 7 with iOS 9 via swift. I created a bridging header (because of swift), imported the ApplePlayM4.h and was able to call the PlayM4_GetPort method. Please note the HikVision library is only compiled for device architectures, amrv7/armv64 and not i386 that is why it won't work in the simulator and only on a physical device.