# iOS: -ObjC gives "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 error"

Tags: ios, ios6, linker

I have a static library with category. If I dont use the category specific part it compiles fine and it works but to use the category methods I included -ObjC in other linker flags. It now gives "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" error for the same library componenets. Any idea why that might be?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 2):

your static library wasn't compiled for armv7, it probably contains only armv6 code, or maybe, worst case i86 one

you need to recompile your static library to include armv7 (and armv7s by the same occasion)