# Link Errors with Parse.framework iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, automatic-ref-counting, parse-platform

I tried importing the parse framework in my project.  I made sure it is liked with my project and I couldn't find anything about whether it is 'arc sensitive' or not.  My project is arc based.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      ___22-[PFCommandCache init]_block_invoke in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache dealloc] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils deleteFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection", referenced from:
      -[PFHTTPCommand scheduleInCurrentThread] in Parse(PFHTTPCommand.o)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection", referenced from:
      -[PFHTTPCommand scheduleInCurrentThread] in Parse(PFHTTPCommand.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Right now the only line of code I have is in the app delegate.  The first is referencing the framework `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` and `[Parse setApplicationId:@"appID" clientKey:@"clientID"];`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Make sure you link against the `SystemConfiguration` and the `Security` framework in your project. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7/6429568#6429568) for more details. As Hector pointed out in the comments, all of the required frameworks for Parse can be found in the [iOS Quick Start Guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart).

- AudioToolbox.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- libz.1.1.3.dylib
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- Security.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: Ahhh missed that!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok thanks. Probably should have looked a bit closer.  Thanks.

Comment: I also needed MobileCoreServices as well.

Comment: All of the required frameworks should be covered by the iOS QuickStart Guide https://parse.com/apps/quickstart

Comment: I looked too quickly.  Thank's everyone!  Total irresponsibility on my part.

Comment: I still get similar error. My error complains about `armv7` though.  I'm using CocoaPods. Here is output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CfegdRyP

Comment: @ruslan log that as a seperate question. Its a different problem

Comment: @HectorRamos what libz.dylib do we add? 1.2.5?

Answer (score 5):

Add MobileCoreServices.framework from your project in addition to these frameworks

-Accounts.framework

-AudioToolbox.framework

-CFNetwork.framework

-CoreGraphics.framework

-CoreLocation.framework

-libz.dylib

-MobileCoreServices.framework

-QuartzCore.framework

-Security.framework

-Social.framework

-StoreKit.framework

-SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: That didn't work for me despite adding all those to the project

Answer (score -2):

I had to add "**$(inherited)**" to the **Framework Search Paths** in **Build Settings** to get it work.