# Xcode Linking Error with Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I have integrated Parse in one of my new apps and copied the code from an another app of mine. But now im getting this huge error. I see many Facebook related stuff but I am not using that.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
      +[PF_FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_FBSettings.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache dealloc] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[PFFile getMimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___26-[PF_FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___39-[PF_FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___39-[PF_FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for your Time.

Comment: You didn't follow the "Get Started" -- You have to add all the dependent frameworks to your project.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319944/2274694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Parse QuickStart info on which libraries that need to be included, and make sure that those are included. If others are also included, and you don't need them, remove them.

Comment: Im so stupid. I totally forgot about the other Frameworks. I have them in my other Apps but I just forgot them. But thank you :P