# CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize making problems

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, core-media

This is my code:

```
-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer );
    CGSize imageSize = CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize( imageBuffer );
    // also in the 'mediaSpecific' dict of the sampleBuffer

    NSLog( @"frame captured at %.fx%.f", imageSize.width, imageSize.height );
}
```

(It is not really relevant for the question, but this a function of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`)

Anyway, the problem is that `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` `CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize` are not recognised. I got the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
```

It is a standard error:[Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)
But the solutions not working for me: 
- I added the framework to Link Binary With Libraries correctly. 
- I imported `<CoreMedia/CMSampleBuffer.h>`, which contains this classes in the .h.

So what is the problem???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add the CoreMedia.framework. Go to your target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and add it.