# zbar sdk view third party library error in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, zbar-sdk

I am using z bar SDK in x code 5 when i am archiving its getting following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCaptureReader captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libzbar.a(ZBarCaptureReader.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferIsValid", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCaptureReader captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libzbar.a(ZBarCaptureReader.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferDataIsReady", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCaptureReader captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libzbar.a(ZBarCaptureReader.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCaptureReader captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libzbar.a(ZBarCaptureReader.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you missed the one of the frameworks - `Core Media`.

Check the following integration link for ZBar sdk.
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html#integration

Answer (score 3):

Remove **armv7s arm64 Architectures** only use the **armv7** and solve your problem.

**Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures -> Delete armv7s arm64**

Comment: Worth noting is that you can specify for instance to run armv7 only for simulations but not for release which is important in my case.

Comment: This solution is overkill. This error is almost always due to not linking against `CoreMedia.framework`, as @iNeal suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Importing  a header and do not linking against the correct library will cause that error.  Check you have imported the correct libraries.  A more complete answer can be found here

[Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)