# Error : There is no SDK with specified name or path 'Users/.…./Project/armv7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

When I am trying to run my app from Xcode 5, Its showing me this error and app is not running. App was working fine with Xcode 4.6 but when I switched to Xcode 5 its showing this error.

`There is no SDK with specified name or path 'Users/.…./Project/armv7`.

```
Error : Composite SDK failed : unknown error.
```

I have tried everything that but still its not working.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: @user3081522:Is your problem solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Project info window and under build settings do the following.

```
Set "Base SDK for All Configuration" to latest available sdk on your system.
```

Quit your xCode and and open it again.

This should solve your problem.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with build setting Architecture "armv7 armv7s armv6". If then it still shows an error, better to quit the Xcode, and run it again.

Comment: @BergQuester This is have tried already. Its not working for me.

Comment: @user3081522 I just made some minor edits to this answer, Laxmi is the one who actually wrote it.