# Simulator OK Device compile Error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s

Tags: ios, frameworks, compilation, armv7

Xcode5.0 + IOS7.0

I am able to run my app in ios simulator, but when comes to device, it run into compile error.

```
`Underfined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCalendar", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in DateUtil.o
  "_kCFRunLoopDefaultMode", referenced from:
       -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
       -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o`
```

[image]

I have search a lot in stackflow, here is a good topic about [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)
but none is work for me

```
 The puzzle come across me is that debugging with iphone5c, 
 the framework used comes from IphoneSimulator showed on the picture, it is wired.
 I tried to add iphoneOS Framework by hand, still the compile info is IphoneSimulator.
```

PS:I can run Hello world demo on iphone5c.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the Reachablity probably into your target.

Check it here:

[image]

Comment: sorry, i don't get what you mean. Do you mean to add the Reachablity.m to Compile Sources. I code in xcode5, and i am a newbibe actually, can you give me more detail, thx.