# Applovin - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, unity-game-engine, applovin

I have integrated Applovin in my Unity project. I then exported my project to iOS and tried to build it. I ended up with the following errors.

```
Ld /Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Products/test.app/test normal armv7
    cd /Users/macintoshuser/Documents/Freelance/WorldWarII_iOS
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Products -L/Users/macintoshuser/Documents/WWII -L/Users/macintoshuser/Documents/WWII/Libraries -F/Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Products -filelist /Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework AdSupport -framework Foundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -lAppLovinSdk -lChartboost -liPhone-lib -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/macintoshuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejrmcaclygycsecppqwiuptnzhsa/Build/Products/test.app/test

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__AppLovinSetMaritalStatus", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetLanguage", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetKeywords", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetInterests", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetIncome", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetVerboseLoggingOn", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetGender", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinHasPreloadedInterstitial", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetCountry", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetAdWidth", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetEducation", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetCarrier", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinPutExtra", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinPreloadInterstitial", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinInitializeSdk", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetBirthYear", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinShowAd", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetSdkKey", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinIsInterstitialShowing", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetEthnicity", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinSetAdPosition", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinShowInterstitial", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "__AppLovinHideAd", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have been trying different solutions to fix my code but none of them seems to help. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just making sure that you have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?rq=1

Comment: I have read and tried it before. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the existing architectures to armv6 only and it worked. The Applovin Unity Plugin has old library and only supports armv6 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens when you add plugins or extensions to your project that need a framwork from ios, check if it does, and once you deploy your project to xcode check add the framework before compiling.

Comment: Yes, I have already added the required frameworks my plugin requires.

Answer (score 0):

you can change architecture to arm6 or you have to check whether unity support arm7 from project build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I dragged and dropped the files in Xcode from Finder. Instead when I do two fingers click and "Add files to 'Project_Name'", it worked.