# Google Analytics doesn't work on new iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I have created a new iOS project and added Google Analytics support following by official instructions.

I've added to Frameworks:

```
libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
AdSupport.framework
CoreData.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
```

But it doesn't work with the errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/.../Sources/GoogleAnalytics'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from:
      -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix it? And does it support **arm64**?

Comment: chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Have you added all require frameworks?

Comment: Aman, it doesn't help.

Comment: Gaurav, what frameworks are required? I've added all of them following official and unofficial instructions!

Comment: From this errors: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from: ... It looks like you have missed adding Core Data frameworks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for all! The following steps helped me:

1. Remove `CoreData.framework`.
2. Add again `CoreData.framework`.

**arm64** is now supported. Thanks to Amar.

Now I should fix the last warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/.../Sources/GoogleAnalytics'
```

It happens because I work with the project on different users.

Answer (score 47):

From Google Analytics [developer page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)

> The Google Analytics SDK uses the CoreData and SystemConfiguration frameworks, so you will need to add the following to your application target's linked libraries:
>
> - libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
> - AdSupport.framework
> - CoreData.framework
> - SystemConfiguration.framework
> - libz.dylib

Looks like you are missing out `CoreData.framework`.

---

Running the `lipo -info` command on the GA library.

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

Gives result,

```
Architectures in the fat file: libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

So it does support arm64.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Altaveron Could you run  the command I mentioned and check what architectures are supported by google analytics lib? Maybe it does not support `armv7`.

Comment: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: @Altaveron Yeah it does support.

Comment: @Altaveron Could you try building the **CuteAnimals** example project that comes bundled with the Google Analytics sdk?

Comment: The official getting started page doesn't mention libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a, adding that solved my linker issues.

Answer (score 4):

You should add the `libsqlite3.0.dylib`file to your frameworks.

To do this, under the projects target, on the general tab, you will find "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", just select the '+' button, and add the framework from there