# Is there GoogleAnalyticsServicesIOS sdk which supports both armv7 and arm64?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, arm

I want to support Architecture armv7 and arm64. I had choose "Standard Architectures(armv7, arm64). For supporting "Google Analytics" i had imported `"Google Analytics SDK 1.2.0"`. If i build an app then its showing `"libGoogleConversionTracking.a, missing required architecture arm64"`
 I had followed the answer of Ryan Romanchuk in the following link "[Unable to link GoogleAnalytics 3.01 with XCode 5 (missing required architecture x86_64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934043/unable-to-link-googleanalytics-3-01-with-xcode-5-missing-required-architecture)". From that link i had downloaded and imported "`GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.12`".If i build an app then its showing error as follows.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
```

Is there any "Google Analytics Services IOS SDK" available which supports both "armv7 and arm64" ? Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: Mr.Amar answer in the following link had worked well.
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008892/google-analytics-doesnt-work-on-new-ios-project

Answer (score 2):

As of now almost everyone is running with xcode 6 probably in next four months new xcode 7 will arrive. So the googleanalytics also will follow the new architecture I think they have probably running with armv7s.

You have only option is to try using the downgraded version of the Google analytics.

Comment: Thanks, please see the following link for exact answer in Comment