# Xcode 5 project runs on simulator 3.5 but gives linker error on device

Tags: c++, ios, paypal, xcode5

When ever i am running the code on the simulator it work fine but on device it give me following error.

ld: library not found for -lz
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i have added paypal sdk in the project , without that sdk it works on device. please suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7/10170293#10170293 look at

Answer (score 1):

try to add  `libz.dylib` in your Target lib phase

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to select 'destination' while copying the sdk into your project, so delete sdk and add it again in your project and remember to select 'destination'