# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I am integrate LinkedInIOS Login Demo with my current application from: 
https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

Also add supporting classes of "AFNetworking".

And It's gives me an error as mention below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please suggest me any solution about it. My deployment target was 5.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Thanks iPatel Problem was resolved. The program needs to add MobileCoreServices.framework
After adding this framework error was resolved.

Comment: Cool ;) Then put it as answer and accept it, So, any developer who have same problem as like you, he/she will be save his/her time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That problem was resolved. As possible issue for that kind of problem was shown at below question:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

But in my case I need to add MobileCoreServices.framework

By adding this framework problem was resolved.

Thanks.