# multiple errors with my audio toolbox

Tags: xcode, audiotoolbox

i have 3 errors and one warning when trying to play sound on my app. i am fairly new to xcode.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/harrisschrick/Documents/Test app/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/harrisschrick/Documents/Test app/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[humordepotViewController viewDidLoad] in humordepotViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[humordepotViewController PlayAudioButton:] in humordepotViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

any help at all would be amazing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: how does this relate to armv7 ?

Comment: Can you show us how you compiled your code ?