# Adding BuddySDK platform to existing project that contains RestKit

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm trying to add BuddySDK to existing project which contains following pods installed:

```
platform:ios, '7.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23'
pod 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'
```

After adding pod 'BuddySDK', '~> 2.0' to the project I'm getting error in Xcode like below:

```
 /Users/Damiano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-bgsmofalkolyjqamlxutjirazrta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a(BPAFURLRequestSerialization.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPBodyPart in:
    /Users/Damiano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-bgsmofalkolyjqamlxutjirazrta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a(AFHTTPClient.o)
    /Users/Damiano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-bgsmofalkolyjqamlxutjirazrta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a(BPAFURLRequestSerialization.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPBodyPart in:
    /Users/Damiano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-bgsmofalkolyjqamlxutjirazrta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a(AFHTTPClient.o)
    /Users/Damiano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-bgsmofalkolyjqamlxutjirazrta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a(BPAFURLRequestSerialization.o)
ld: 39 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I was searching for solution on other asked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) but without any luck.
It looks like an error occurred because BuddySDK contains AFNetworking classes which already exist in RestKit. 
[image]

After deleting RestKit pod from Podfile the problem disappears.
Does anyone can tell me what should I do to successfully install both pods (RestKit and BuddySDK) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy provides both a pre-compiled library as well as Cocoapods support. Any open source dependencies are "wrapped" into Buddy-specific names as to prevent the duplicate symbol problem when deploying as a pre-compiled binary.

I believe the problem you are having is that you have included BuddySDK with both the pre-compiled library *as well as* the Cocoapod.

Keith's explanation is true for most cases, however :).

Comment: Since his duplicate symbols are from AFNetworking I think that's what's getting included twice.

Comment: @KeithSmiley It is. The issue was resolved, and was a "bug" in the way we work around duplicate symbols. https://github.com/BuddyPlatform/Buddy-iOS-SDK/issues/123

Answer (score 1):

Both RestKit and BuddySDK rely on AFNetworking. The problem is that [BuddySDK's spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/BuddySDK/2.0.0/BuddySDK.podspec.json#L19) does not add this as a dependency in CocoaPods but bundles AFNetworking themselves. Because of this there are duplicate symbols when multiple versions of AFNetworking are included in your project. To fix this you should open an issue on the BuddySDK [GitHub page](https://github.com/BuddyPlatform/Buddy-iOS-SDK) so they can fix this.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I've added issue to the BuddySDK GitHub page. Here is the link: https://github.com/BuddyPlatform/Buddy-iOS-SDK/issues/123