# Integrating firebase with an iOS project that includes tokbox and parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, firebase, opentok, tokbox

Has anyone been able to integrate Firebase into an iOS project that already runs tokbox and parse.com?

When I [include `-ObjC` per Firebase instructions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html), I get lots of apple mach-o linker errors (pasted below). If I do not include `-objC`, the project compiles without error, but then Firebase has runtime error (also pasted below). xcode 5.1.1, parse 1.2.20, tokbox 2.2.1, firebase 1.1.10.

I have seen apps with tokbox and firebase living happy together, it should be possible.

(1) errors when include '-ojbC'

Ld /Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Call\ Me.app/Call\ Me normal armv7
    cd "/Users/tmr/Google Drive/software/xcode/Call Me"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/tmr/Google\ Drive/software/xcode/Call\ Me -F/Users/tmr/Downloads/OpenTok-iOS-2.2.1 -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/tmr/Downloads -filelist /Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Intermediates/Call\ Me.build/Debug-iphoneos/Call\ Me.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Call\ Me.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -framework Firebase -lc++ -licucore -framework XCTest -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lxml2 -lsqlite3 -framework GLKit -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreTelephony -framework OpenTok -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Parse -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Intermediates/Call\ Me.build/Debug-iphoneos/Call\ Me.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Call\ Me_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/tmr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Call_Me-gnseubspfupoqccmstcxpnbpkvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Call\ Me.app/Call\ Me

ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(2) run time error when do not include other linker '-objC'

2014-08-01 00:09:48.756 Call Me[5817:60b] -[FRepo youForgotToSetMinusObjCInTheOtherLinkerFlagsInYourXCodeProject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155831f0

Comment: The error message seems to have some good pointers: "missing required architecture armv7 in file", such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

for my ios project, the solutions was add two frameworks:

```
FacebookSDK
Social
```

integrating firebase with parse and tokbox worked after adding the two frameworks.

Comment: thanks for helping answer a TokBox question! If you'd like a TokBox TShirt, email song@tokbox.com

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for other SDKs, but for OpenTok to work properly,

Make sure you are using the latest version of all the SDK. For OpenTok, you should download from here: https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/

Under build settings, make sure valid architectures is only armv7. remove arm64 and armv7s.

Leave Base SDK empty or set it to iOS 7.