# iOS Paypal SDK Integration Compilation issues

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm trying to get Paypal's iOS SDK working. I have followed the instructions in the readme but the build fails with the error below

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSExtensionItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPayPalMobile.a(OnePasswordExtension.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSItemProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPayPalMobile.a(OnePasswordExtension.o)
  "_kUTTypePropertyList", referenced from:
      -[OnePasswordExtension processExtensionItem:completion:] in libPayPalMobile.a(OnePasswordExtension.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This same error occurs when building the sample application, so I have ruled out my project settings.

Can anybody tell me what I've missed?

Comment: Hey look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Thanks, but this same issue occurs in the sample app too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was down to the new version of the Paypal API requiring Xcode 6, while I was attempting to compile on Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1):

add the path of the library in the "Library Search Path"

$(PROJECT_DIR)/XXXX/MyFramework/GoogleAdWords

EDIT : Maybe the sample is wrong ...

Comment: Thanks, but the directory is already in the search path for the sample application. Not ruling out a bad sample app, but I think the instructions are more likely at fault here.

Comment: is the library is linked in "Build Phases" ?

Comment: I had the same problem when I use ScanPay library, I fixed it changing "Architectures" to "Standard architectures armv7, armv7s" without including 64-bit.
But is not a nice solution that mean paypal is not compilant to 64Bit devices

Comment: Yes. Architectures is also set to standard.

Comment: try to remove 64 bit -> armv7, armv7s only

Comment: The library is build for armv7 armv7s i386 and x86_64, so that seems OK to me.

Comment: did you already check the "Build Phases" library linked list ?

Comment: Yes I did, it has all .m files included.

Comment: NO check the "link binary with libraries" section. did you see the paypal library ?

Comment: Problem is solved, master only supports Xcode 6 and I'm running on 5. It was in the release notes.

Comment: great. go download the GM version on dev.apple.com