# Swift set content compression resistance

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Using Swift again, am I missing something?

I have this line:

```
self.itemDescription?.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
```

But Xcode is giving me an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_UILayoutPriorityRequired"
```

Another one of Swift's quirks?

Comment: I can reproduce this and I'd agree it looks wrong. I'd probably just raise a bug report and use 1000 for now; presumably something isn't linking against whatever module the defined symbols are in (or they're not actually defined anywhere...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange exception in layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881872/strange-exception-in-layouts)

Comment: Have voted to close this. Apple hasn't fixed this issue yet = /

Comment: don't do it. This question googles better. In OSX swift apps, the same problem exists with NSLayoutPriorityRequired and other layout constants.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solution: replace `UILayoutPriorityRequired` with 1000

```
self.itemDescription?.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
```

This is not a bug. It is a misunderstanding of how Objective-C libraries are imported into Swift. It should be understood how Swift imports code (even from the Apple UIKIt Libraries) from Objective-C into Swift.

UILayoutPriority is a float. In Objective-C, a couple of values have been pre-defined for us. The pre-defined values appear to be an enum. We might expect that the same enums would be available to us in Swift.

The documentation does seem to imply an enum:

SWIFT (Documentation)

```
typealias UILayoutPriority = Float
```

OBJECTIVE-C (Documentation)

```
enum {
   UILayoutPriorityRequired = 1000,
   UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh = 750,
   UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow = 250,
   UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel = 50,
};
typedef float UILayoutPriority;
```

But in Xcode, if you ask to see the defintion of one of these enum values (UILayoutPriorityRequired, for example), you will see that they are actually defined in the header file as constant floats.

OBJECTIVE-C (Header file)

```
typedef float UILayoutPriority;
static const UILayoutPriority UILayoutPriorityRequired NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) = 1000; // A required constraint.  Do not exceed this.
static const UILayoutPriority UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) = 750; // This is the priority level with which a button resists compressing its content.
static const UILayoutPriority UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) = 250; // This is the priority level at which a button hugs its contents horizontally.
```

So although we may like to think of the pre-defined layout priorities as enum values (as the documentation suggests) the layout priorities are not really defined as enums; they are defined as constant floats.

A hint that there is a mis-match -- for anyone that knows the C programming language -- is that a C enum may only contain `int` values. The following is legal and will compile:

```
enum myEnum {
    JGCEnum_one = 1, // this is O.K.
    JGCEnum_two,
    JGCEnum_three
} JGCEnum;
```

But we can not define floats as values for C enums. The following will not compile:

```
enum myEnum {
    JGCEnum_one = 1.5, // compile error
    JGCEnum_two,
    JGCEnum_three
} JGCEnum;
```

Objective-C enums are the same as C enums (Swift enums are different). It is important to know if we are dealing with actual integers or floats. Because integers can be defined using the NS_ENUM macro, which can then be imported to Swift as a Swift enum.

The iBook says

> Swift imports as a Swift enumeration any C-style enumeration marked with the NS_ENUM macro. This means that the prefixes to enumeration value names are truncated when they are imported into Swift, whether they’re defined in system frameworks or in custom code.

Excerpt From: [Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” iBooks](https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l)

That means that if UILayoutPriority *had* been defined as an integer using the NS_ENUM macro, it would have been imported into Swift as Swift enum. This is the case for UILayoutConstraintAxis.

SWIFT (Documentation)

```
enum UILayoutConstraintAxis : Int {
    case Horizontal
    case Vertical
}
```

OBJECTIVE-C (Documentation)

```
enum {
   UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal = 0,
   UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical = 1
};
typedef NSInteger UILayoutConstraintAxis;
```

Looking at the Objective-C header file confirms what the documentation says.

OBJECTIVE-C (Header File)

```
//
// UIView Constraint-based Layout Support
//

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UILayoutConstraintAxis) {
    UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal = 0,
    UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical = 1
};
```

So there are at least two ways to know if a pre-defined value you are used to using in Objective-C is available in Swift:

1. check the documentation
2. check the header file in Objective-C (found by right-clicking the value and then selecting "Jump to Definition")

There is one more way to see if a typedef you are used to using is a constant or an enum. In code, test to see if the address of the constant exists. Constants have a memory address, while enums do not. See the code below.

```
// this line will compile and run just fine. 
// UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh is a constant and has a memory address
// the value will be true if the device is running iOS 6.0 or later
// and false otherwise
BOOL predefinedValueIsAvailable = (NULL != &UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh);

// this line will not compile
// UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal is an enum (NOT a constant) 
// and does not have a memory address
predefinedValueIsAvailable = (NULL != &UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal);
```

### References

- [Using Layout Priority in Swift](http://jasoncross-ios-development.blogspot.com/2015/04/using-uilayoutpriority-in-swift.html)
- Xcode Documentation (iOS 8.2)
- [Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” iBooks](https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l)

Comment: While this is a great answer describing what causes the problem, it doesn't actually say a solution.

Comment: This explains why `UILayoutPriority.Required` doesn't work, because UILayoutPriority is not a Swift enum. However, the OP is using `UILayoutPriorityRequired`, which is defined in the Swift "header" as `let UILayoutPriorityRequired: UILayoutPriority`. I would think that attempting to use a constant defined in the Swift header resulting in a linker error _is_ a bug, and not just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi @mpalmer, There is no such thing as a Swift "header". When an Objective-C Framework is imported into Swift, such as UIKit, the import process makes the Framework available as a  Swift API. The Swift API is **not** identical to the Objective-C API. Therefore the statement "attempting to use a constant defined in the Swift header" is referring to something that does not exist, hence the misunderstanding.

Comment: @JasonCross absolutely correct. However, this was still a bug. After experiencing this same issue, I filed a bug report with Apple, and the issue was fixed with the iOS 9 SDK. Using `UILayoutPriorityRequired` now successfully links, as expected.

Answer (score 11):

One thing to keep in mind is that, even though `UILayoutPriority` is an alias to `Float`, you're using Swift and you can use an extension to create semantic constants for these values:

```
extension UILayoutPriority {
    static var Low: Float { return 250.0 }
    static var High: Float { return 750.0 }
    static var Required: Float { return 1000.0 }
}
```

Then you're code can read as:

```
self.itemDescription?.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.Required, forAxis: .Vertical);
```

I've done this myself in one of my projects and thought it may be useful.

Comment: you can remove ;

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this:

```
self.itemDescription?.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(<float number>), forAxis: .Vertical)
```

**Example:**

```
self.itemDescription?.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(750), forAxis: .Vertical)
```