# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 for Cocoapods libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, armv7, xcode-project

I stumbled upon a problem on a project that I need to work on. The project use Cocoapods for managing its libraries. I run `pod install` as usual to get started but xcode give me errors. I got `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7` as you can see in the image below:

[image]

All this symbols are the libraries that I use with my project. Eg. AFNetworking, RNBlurModalView. I tried to remove all the Cocoapods related file from the project and running `pod install` again, but it still doesn't solved the problem.

What I have done so far:

- Clean the project and build again.
- Removing Cocoapods related files and running `pod install` again.
- Tried to add the class in Compile Sources in Project Target, but can't. The class is in Pods workspace.
- Set Build Active Architecture Only from `YES` to `NO`.

I also try the solutions from the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7), but none of it is working for me.

If it helps, I'm using xCode6 and Cocoapods `0.34.4`. The project valid architectures is `armv7 and armv7s`.

**Update:** When running `pod install --verbose`

```
Integrating client project

Integrating target `Pods` (`AIYOCore.xcodeproj` project)

[!] The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:

    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


[!] The `Project [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Project [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It seems like you don't have `$(inherited)` in OTHER LINKER FLAGS. Please post output of the `pod install`

Comment: Hi, I've just updated my question with parts of the logs which I think is relevant. Mind looking at it?

Comment: as I wrote before, add $(inherited) in OTHER_LDFLAGS for all targets as a first line

Comment: The habit of ignoring warnings! Damn!

Comment: I stumbled with the same problem I have added $(inherited) and its not working.. still showing that error above. but I can build with arm64 only.. any idea why this is still appearing?

Comment: may be some of your libraries are supplied as a prebuild binaries with arm64 arch only?

Comment: Your solution works just in one hit. You saved my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow I went through all the steps in this trouble shooting guide (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html), and still nothing. This though, WORKED! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to clean the build folder (⌥⇧⌘K).

[image]