# BitBucket SourceTree Pod Update have thousands of pull request

Tags: ios, cocoapods, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, actionsheetpicker

I don't know if the title goes with the question but this is the first time I'm facing this problem and I don't know what has happened and there is no error so can't really tell what is the issue. So here is what I did:

- I updated pods. As far as I remember this is the first time I updated
  after updating to iOS 10.
- I added `pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'` and `#pod 'IQActionSheetPickerView', '~> 1.0'` it updated fine without any errors.
- There were some `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7` which I solved with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619389/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-cocoapods-iphone-5). I only cleaned the Build Folder but I didn't changed `Build Active Architecture Only` like it is said.

After some time this happened:
[image] and [image]
I haven't pulled or pushed anything yet. But by looking at what the pull request is it has these uncommitted changes.
[image]
So this is all the information I think is required to define this problem. Let me know if you want to know more.
Based on a comment I'm sharing the branches I have:
[image]

Comment: Haha, I have the same! I think it was after running `pod spec lint` or similar, looks like it's pulling every cocoapod.

Comment: It looks like you aren't on the right branch when you performed the pod update. I would reset your branch, change to the correct branch (in this case it looks like the master branch) and do a pull to make sure you have the latest changes. Once done create a new branch from there and update your pods like you did before. - EDIT: Sorry I thought that was your repo, but thats the cocoa pods repo?

Comment: @JamesP bro then what is the solution for that?

Comment: @dlbuckley see my updated question. There is only one branch which is the master.

Comment: @dlbuckley I didn't get the edit part? My project is on bitBucket and yes the repo is with pods. So everything is there.

Comment: I thought the source tree screen shot was for your repository, but it's the cocoa pods repository right? My original assumption and advice was incorrect because of that :) Maybe look at the `pod repo` tools part of cocoapods to see if those can help you.

Comment: Check the origin of your repo, for some reason mine had been changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is how I solved it. May be this can be only for my case:
If you have updated to iOS 10 you need to update your gem and cocoapods.

1. Open Terminal
2. Write `gem update`
3. Then `gem install cocoapods`

Then `cd <path of project>` and `pod install`. By doing this the pull requests are no longer happening.
I was in luck as I deleted the whole project and then again made a clone from bitbucket which was till my last push and after that push I just updated the pods. After the new clone I ran the above mentioned process and now it's working fine.