# ObjC Category doesn't link to iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cocoapods, sdwebimage, objective-c-category

I'm using SDWebImage with CocoaPods, and the app I'm working on must support iOS7.

After installing SDWebImage version 4.0.0 with CocoaPods, I import it into a class with `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`.

I use one of the category's methods, `sd_setImageWithURL:`, to asynchronously download an image.

This works fine on iOS8-10. But for some reason (only on iOS7), the app crashes saying that the `sd_setImageWithURL:` is an unrecognized selector.

Why would the category not load properly on only one OS? This doesn't make any sense to me at all. :/

**Update:**
I ran an analysis on the project, and I noticed this warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file <path/to/file>/libSDWebImage.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): <path/to/file>/libSDWebImage.a
```

(The path was really long. I replaced it with `<path/to/file>`)

As I suspected, this warning does not show up when running on newer versions of iOS, which also use a different architecture, arm64.

So, it looks like the library `libSDWebImage.a` is being build for arm64. What can I do about this?

Comment: Did you use use_frameworks! ? iOS 7 doesn't support frameworks.

Comment: Nope, I did not. I didn't know that though!

Comment: I found a warning from XCode and put it in the main post. Does this ring a bell, maybe?

Comment: As I suspected, the warning doesn't show up on newer versions of iOS (which are on newer devices, like the iPhone 6, which uses arm64). What am I supposed to do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO in Build Settings, then did the "deep clean" as suggested by the answer here: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: cocoaPods iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619389/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-cocoapods-iphone-5)

That seemed to solve the issue for me.