# After updating Facebook SDK to latest version 4.1.0 using cocoapods

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods, xcode8

Currently I am using Xcode8.2.1 and recently i have updated Facebook SDK to 4.1.0 using pod. Im facing the below error, please let me know if I made anything wrong.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKGraphRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyAccountViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyAccountViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKProfile", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyAccountViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What programming language do you use? Objective-C, Swift?

Comment: We used both  Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: @Joakim this is a better dupe: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 for Cocoapods libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27286226/2415822)

Comment: @JAL already I have tried the scenario as u mentioned in the above URL, but issue has not been fixed