# Xcode 6 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode6

getting errors

```
like ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while i m trying to build project , it's build successfully in iphone 6 and i phone 5s but when i m trying to build in other simulator like iphone 4s then it's showing errors .

i have just updated my MAC OS and x-code version from 5.1 to 6.1.

I have also checked i have no duplicated file or framwork in my project still getting errors so i m not able to create .app file ..

Please help me if any one having solution for that kind of issues ...might be this one is duplicate Question but i already go through all stack post and others .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: You need to look at the full linker output, it will tell which symbols are duplicate the the files they are in.

Comment: i have looked already but having still issue ...can you please help

Comment: There may be some of the files / images being duplicated in your project. The complete linker error will be having the name of the file inside it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MslOE.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes simply remove the Bolts framworks which also somehow already included in FB SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the 91 duplicates. What worked for me was simply to remove the Bolts.framework which seems to be somehow already included in Facebook new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i found the files that duplicate symbol in project navigator, and delete them select `Remove Reference`, then drag these files in finder to Xcode project navigator select `Create group` and the correct target, don't check `Copy item if needed`, it work