# Undefined architecture for armv7 - importing C libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, static-libraries, fips

I am trying to import and use OpenSSL FIPS validated object module in my iOS project. When I build the project I get this error saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::string::clear()", referenced from:
  +[CryptoUtilities getSeed:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
  +[CryptoUtilities getKey:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
"___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
  vtable for WBXML::CWBXMLParser in CWBXMLParser.o
"std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  WBXML::CWBXMLParser::LoadWBXMLHeader(std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long&) in CWBXMLParser.o
  WBXML::CWBXMLParser::LoadTagContents(WBXML::CTag*, std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long&, unsigned short&, bool&) in CWBXMLParser.o
  +[CryptoUtilities getKey:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
 "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<WBXML::CTag>::deallocate(WBXML::CTag*, unsigned long) in CTag.o
    __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) in CryptoUtilities.o

   // This goes for some more functions and then
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know this question has been asked and answered at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7). I tried all the solutions that are mentioned but I am not able to fix this issue.

Here are the things/settings I tried to fix the problem.

- I have added the libs and the canister in the linked frameworks and libraries section.
- Since it is a lib, i do not have any .m files to add.
- I tried changing the C++ compiler to Compiler Default, LLVM , GNU and none of them worked.
- I tried adding -ObjC in the other linker flags.
- I tried extern C when including the header files. The header files' definition also has extern C correctly used.

**Update :**

I do have set the compiler settings correctly as mentioned below.

[image]

Also if this would be any help in figuring out this error. It is when running this script in the runscript phase that I get these errors that are mentioned.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YEebn2p8HKhc7lxUWa3xMHXWt1cELXLm3AoKElbEyuU/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me.

**Update2 :**

Output of xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info CryptoUtilities.o is
    Non-fat file : CryptoUtilities.o is architecture: armv7

More details about the errors : 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CqSa_tAsQP1JY_IxvXLDyYyQUI0iebV_REiCquwDXyk/edit?usp=sharing

Please help. I am in this position for around a month.

Comment: `__gnu_cxx::...` is from the GNU C++ runtime (`-stdlib=libstdc++`). You must compile WBXML against the LLVM C++ runtime (`-stdlib=libc++`). If the libraries were mixed/matched the opposite way, then you'd be getting errors about missing `__1::...`

Comment: Also, add the output of `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info CryptoUtilities.o`. But it looks like you are not using the correct C++ runtimes.

Comment: @jww I changed the dialect and library to ( compiler default, compiler default ) and also to libc++. It gave me the same error. Also added output of the cmd above.

Answer (score 0):

```
"std::string::clear()", referenced from:
  +[CryptoUtilities getSeed:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
  +[CryptoUtilities getKey:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
"___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
  vtable for WBXML::CWBXMLParser in CWBXMLParser.o
"std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  WBXML::CWBXMLParser::LoadWBXMLHeader(std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long&) in CWBXMLParser.o
  WBXML::CWBXMLParser::LoadTagContents(WBXML::CTag*, std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long&, unsigned short&, bool&) in CWBXMLParser.o
  +[CryptoUtilities getKey:::] in CryptoUtilities.o
 "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<WBXML::CTag>::deallocate(WBXML::CTag*, unsigned long) in CTag.o
    __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) in CryptoUtilities.o
```

This has nothing to do with the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module.

`___cxa_pure_virtual` and friends are part of the C++ runtime. It looks like you are mixing and matching `libc++` (used by Xcode) and `libstdc++` (provided by GNU).

You should use `libc++` for everything because of Xcode. That means you ensure `-stdlib=libc++` is on all command lines.

If you can't use `libc++`  everywhere, then you need to use `libstdc++` everywhere. The Xcode setting is shown below under ***C++ Standard Library***:

[image]

The image above is for Crypto++ using `libstdc++` (GNU library, not Xcode default). Though its for a Crypto++ question, it applies here, too.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I have updated the question with more details.