# aisle411 iOS SDK missing required architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, indoor-positioning-system

Hi I am currently creating an indoor mapping application for iOS using aisle411 SDK. I am trying to instantiate MapController to see how it works, but I am getting a compile error :

> warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/comical/Documents/Code/Repository/Git/Indoor-Map-App
>   /Indoor Map App/Views/MapView/MapSDK/libMapSDK.a, missing required
>   architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/comical/Documents/Code/Repository/Git/Indoor-Map-App
>   /Indoor Map App/Views/MapView/MapSDK/libMapSDK.a (3 slices) Undefined
>   symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MapController",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AleMapController.o ld:
>
> symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Is there anyone have similar experience while implementing aisle411? Or do you know what is aisle411 dependencies in iOS? Thanks for your help.

UPDATE : 
After update the SDK, I got this error instead:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
>         __GLOBAL__I_a in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)   "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
>         __GLOBAL__I_a in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)   "std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()", referenced from:
>         std::range_error::~range_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::range_error::~range_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::range_error::~range_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::overflow_error::~overflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::overflow_error::~overflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::overflow_error::~overflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::underflow_error::~underflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         ...   "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
>         std::domain_error::~domain_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::length_error::~length_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::out_of_range::~out_of_range() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::range_error::~range_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::overflow_error::~overflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         std::underflow_error::~underflow_error() in libMapSDK.a(MapController.o)
>         ...
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If you already checked `lipo -info libMapSDK.a`, check the common causes on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?lq=1

Comment: Hmm interesting, I tried some answer from the link, but so far nothing is works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got solution from my friend. He said that I miss libstdc++.6.dylib to build the app with aisle411 SDK. And it finally works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Run `lipo -info libMapSDK.a` and check if there is x86_64 architecture. If not, download the last version, should be 64 bits compatible.

Comment: Hi las, thanks for your answer. I was using the old SDK because I use my friend's code as reference. After updating the SDK I got different error, see update.