# xcode 6:symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Building my Ionic+Parse Project in Xcode v 6.2 gives me this build error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The frameworks that I have added are

[image]

And the build settings look like this
[image]

Any help would be really appreciate

P.S: Trying to run application on an iPad 2

**Update**
The problem is with adding `Parse.Framework` to existing xCode project.
- I tried removing the re adding the `Parse.Framework` (cleaned and built) from project but then it increases build errors.

Comment: Have you tried a build clean then rebuild?

Comment: what is the framework search path? does it correct to link to parse framework?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel yes I have cleaned and project and then build it again

Comment: Try after you changed  `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`

Comment: @LoVo i tried but no effect.

Comment: @vichevstefan can you please tell me where should build search path point? to which folder to file

Comment: if you download parseframework inside /Downloads/Parse then you can add /Downloads/Parse into the framework search path in build settings. Also what I can guess is, please check parse framework is in link libraries at build phase tab

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @vichevstefan I did the same .i.e removed the unnecessary paths to avoid conflict and added ParseFB util framework.. but now it shows 43 errors. the problem is I am not sure how many lib are required. The screen shot has all libs mentioned in Parse Setup guide..

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of struggle.

- Clear the `/platforms` folder
- run `ionic platform add ios`
- Open `/platform/ios` Xcode Project.
- You should see build errors (about 8 or 10)
- **Go to Target> Build settings>Other Linker Flags**
- **Remove the -ObjC from the list if present.**
- Clean and build you're good to go. [image]