# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, linker-errors, cocoapods, mach-o

I am getting a build error when trying to run my `iOS` project on a `real iPhone device`. I don't get this issue when running it on the `Simulator` though.

I am using `Cocoapods` for all my libraries.

Why is this happening? And how do I fix this?

```
Ld /Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/DeployGateSDK.framework/DeployGateSDK normal armv7
    cd /Users/cyrano/Documents/coding_workspace/lfdate/ios/LovelUp/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods -F/Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods -F/Users/cyrano/Documents/coding_workspace/lfdate/ios/LovelUp/Pods/DeployGateSDK/DeployGateSDK1.0.4.embeddedframework -filelist /Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pods-DeployGateSDK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeployGateSDK.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/DeployGateSDK.framework/DeployGateSDK -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -framework DeployGateSDK -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pods-DeployGateSDK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeployGateSDK_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/cyrano/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LovelUp-asynlucucstznmdioyjinbxcqwba/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/DeployGateSDK.framework/DeployGateSDK

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__mh_execute_header", referenced from:
      l001 in DeployGateSDK(DGSApplicationUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Which iPhone model are you deploying to?

Comment: @John It's an `iPhone 4S` updated to `8.3`

Comment: Is `DeployGateSDK` compatible with this version of OS ? Which Xcode you are tested it with ? Does this SDK compiled for `armv7` architecture ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless I am not sure about the compatibility. It is on the cocoapods site and doesn't have much info. I am testing with XCode 6.3. It runs fine on the Simulator but not on my 4S.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7.. Hope it helps you..