# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: after adding an extension target to a react-native project

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I created a react-native project using `react-native init`
I then add an action extension to that project using File -> new -> target -> Action Extension, with the name "Stash"
I try adding a StashView that inherits from UIView, and contains an RCTRootView, as instructed in the [Integration with Existing App instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app.html#add-rctrootview-to-container-view):

Stash/StashView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StashView : UIView

@end
```

Stash/StashView.m:

```
#import "StashView.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation StashView
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8081/stash.ios.bundle";
   NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName: @"Stash"
                                                   launchOptions:nil];
  [self addSubview:rootView];
  rootView.frame = self.bounds;
}
@end
```

When I compile, I get the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in StashView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

The full stack trace:

> Ld
>   /Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stash.appex/Stash
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/danoved/Source/myprojects/ToDoBox
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Intermediates/ToDoBox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Stash.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -OjbC /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit -e _NSExtensionMain -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Intermediates/ToDoBox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Stash_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/danoved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoBox-gmtanlmumdrkqactpypioaempcuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stash.appex/Stash

What am I doing wrong?  Something in the build settings?

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out!

Based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

I had to open the Link Binary with Libraries carrot in the Build Phases of the extension, and add all of the react libraries to it:

[image]