# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting this error, while building IOS project for `react native`:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add all lib*.a from React in **Link Binary With Libraries** section.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429568/988941 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133760/988941 for more details