# iOS Error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, unity-game-engine

I build project that have unity classes inside. And i got this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture `armv7`:

`RegisterAllClassesIPhone()`, referenced fro

`RegisterAllClasses()` in `RegisterMonoModules.o`

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone knows how to handle with this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you see the class `RegisterMonoModules` under *Compile Sources* (select the project -> select *Build Phases*)?

Comment: yes I can see it RegisteredMonoModules.cpp

Comment: So you are mixing C++ and Swift?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: yes i mix c++ and swift

Comment: I'm stuck on this one too

Answer (score 0):

You may forget to add this flag:

Other C Flag:
-DINIT_SCRIPTING_BACKEND=1

Other C++ Flag:
-DINIT_SCRIPTING_BACKEND=1

I met the same issue, and fixed by added the above flags.