# Xcode 6.3.2 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on unity 4.6.2f1 with vuforia 3.0
xcode version 6.3.2

everything is working fine on android and unity player but when I export to Xcode,
it appears over hundred of errors

[image: it shows Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:]

but in my architecture i already remove armv7s

[image]

I have tried for hours and start feeling frustrated..
each build cost 10-15 minutes and errors keep pop up no matter what I do
I have search a lot from Internet but seems like it doesn't get rid of the errors..
anyone had overcome this issue please help me.. thanks

Comment: This project was built on Unity using a Mac or a Windows machine?

Comment: it was built using Mac... Because iOS app development need to be done in Mac OS

Comment: Alright then, please show us your Build Settings in the question?

Comment: The correct tag for Unity3D is `unity3d`

Comment: Please check this link, probably it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: What are your Build Settings especially for IL2CPP.. Universal? What kind of iOS Build are you doing (Simulator / Device)? Maybe you should think about updating Unity, as there is already 4.6.6 out (and even there are already 2 patch releases). There are a lot of bug fixes concerning IL2CPP since 4.6.2. I'd really recommend doing so.

Comment: @AugmentedJacob already attached with screenshot here

Comment: @RajeshMaurya tried but no luck on it

Comment: @d4Rk thanks for suggesting this, i am downloading the latest unity3d version 5.1 and try if it is work or not, will update you guys later

Comment: @Sunny I meant Unity Build Settings. Not Xcode.