# Remote Display Framework

Tags: ios, google-cast

I am attempting to use Google Cast Remote Display.  Simply adding the GoogleCastRemoteDisplay.framework results in linking errors. I have sorted out some, but cannot figure this out...

Anyone have an idea?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kvImage_ARGBToYpCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2", referenced from:
      l034 in GoogleCastRemoteDisplay(libCastRemoteDisplay.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_vImageConvert_ARGB8888To420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8", referenced from:
      l035 in GoogleCastRemoteDisplay(libCastRemoteDisplay.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_vImageConvert_ARGB8888To420Yp8_CbCr8", referenced from:
      l035 in GoogleCastRemoteDisplay(libCastRemoteDisplay.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_vImageConvert_ARGBToYpCbCr_GenerateConversion", referenced from:
      l034 in GoogleCastRemoteDisplay(libCastRemoteDisplay.a-armv7-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by running "pod install" instead of manually bringing in the .framework  However this is a unity project, so there were issues with 
The `Unity-iPhone [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

went to project build settings->Other Linker Flags and added $(inherited)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely right that the Cocoapod is the best way of grabbing the library. If you were pulling it in manually thought, you'll need to link in the appropriate system frameworks, and the regular google-cast-sdk, which is dependends on - you can actually read these from the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/google-cast-remote-display-sdk/2.7.0/google-cast-remote-display-sdk.podspec.json) even if you're not using Cocoapods. These are:

- Accelerate
- AudioToolbox
- CoreMedia
- CoreVideo
- OpenGLES
- QuartzCore

And Metal if using that rendering method.

The functions you listed are from the Accelerate framework.