# Undefined symbols error with Google Analytics and Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics

I'm developing an app with Xcode 7 for iOS with Objetive-C. This app was updated to be fitted with the new Xcode version.

In my MacBook Pro 13' it runs but in my MacBook Pro 15' I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore selectStmtWithTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore hasValidPropertyColumns] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore errorMessage] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl tablePresent:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore removeStatementForQuery:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore finalizeAndClearStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These are my Frameworks:

[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7), may be helpful.

Comment: your **libsqlite3.tbd** is correct is this mac app, sorry  I used analytics in my app , in here I used  **libsqlite3.dylib**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of libsqlite3.tbd, you should use libsqlite3.dylib.

P.S. In Xcode 7 beta, you can't find libsqlite3.dylib by default from the selectable libs in "Link Binary With Libraries". (It could be a bug in beta version) however, option 1, you can manually select libsqlite3.dylib from /usr/lib/, then, it should work. Option 2, use Xcode 7 to select libsqlite3.dylib.

Comment: I can use tbd in my new MacBook Pro, and it runs ok but my problem is why it doesn't run in the other laptop.

Comment: Are you using OS X 10.11 with Xcode 7 beta while other laptop is using OS X 10.10?

Comment: No, in the laptop where my project run I have OSX 10.10.4 with Xcode 7.0 Beta (7A121l) and in the other where I have the crash OSX 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.0 (7A120f)

Comment: That's strange. It's hard to say for sure which caused the problem, since you have both beta OS X and beta Xcode 7.

Comment: I will try to put exactly the same Xcode version in both laptops in order to test if 7A120f has some extra bug

Comment: Installing Xcode 7 Beta 5 (7A176x) solved the problem