# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 after update to IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, armv7

This problem has begun occurring since updating my app for IOS 9 and is driving me crazy. 
There were no problems with the app in IOS 8.4.1

I have listed the problem below first for reference and then after described what i have tried so far:

```
Ld /Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PulseGuard.app/PulseGuard normal armv7
cd /Users/Chris/Documents/pulseguardproject
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Chris/Documents/pulseguardproject/sdk/dependencies -filelist /Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Intermediates/PulseGuard.build/Debug-iphoneos/PulseGuard.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -dead_strip -all_load -lstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lz -framework WFConnector -framework MessageUI -framework ExternalAccessory -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Intermediates/PulseGuard.build/Debug-iphoneos/PulseGuard.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard-fqkhdzxugiorktbjaulqdzejnydu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PulseGuard.app/PulseGuard

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[WFAPIReachability isReachable] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability isReachableViaWWAN] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability isReachableViaWiFi] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability connectionRequired] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability isConnectionOnDemand] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability isInterventionRequired] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability reachabilityFlags] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      ...
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue", referenced from:
      -[WFAPIReachability startNotifier] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability stopNotifier] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[WFAPIReachability startNotifier] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
      -[WFAPIReachability stopNotifier] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[WFAPIReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[WFAPIReachability reachabilityWithHostname:] in WFConnector(WFAPIReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is what i have tried so far:

Updating the WFConnector framework to the latest version which is compatible with IOS 9.
Looked through the Build Settings and removed any reference to the old version of the framework. 
Searched the internet for any other references to the problem, the only one found was here [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) which i have checked through however has not solved my problem.

I did notice that the libz.dylib framework was missing since updating and so have tried searching in /usr/lib/ and manually adding the framework back in, this has not worked, i have also added the new libz.tbd file into the framework list however this also has not fixed the problem.

Can anyone please suggest the correct solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this problem was a missing framework called "SystemConfiguration.framework"
Once this had been added all the errors resolved and the app loaded without issue.