# Compilation error in react native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to build my react native project for release and i am getting the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

can some one help here please i cant figure it out.

Comment: Would this be the answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Have the same problem, any solutions?