# Xcode 7.2 googlemaps Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am using the GoogleMaps iOS SDK in my app and added it with cocoapods. However, after updating xCode from 7.2 I'm suddenly getting the following error: Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMaps'
I already deleted my DerivedData folder, updated cocoapods, reinstalled the GoogleMaps iOS SDK and cleaned and build the framework's scheme and my app's scheme. But nothing helped so far.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the newest library or this is an old project? If it's old then update the library.

Comment: i'm using 1.11.1 googlemaps.framework file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have completed all the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project

I did some research and found this Stack overflow related to your inquiry: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

I hope this may help you.