# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 XCode 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

I know that this is a duplicate question. I followed the answers posted in the other similar Stack Overflow questions and I also tried answers posted on other websites. But, I still get the below error. So, please help me to get rid of this error.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7 Check this

Comment: Please post the text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya I followed up already but I still get error.

Comment: Import uikit framework in your project and write import statement in .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all system classes.  You are somehow failing to link against the `UIKit.framework`.

In order to solve these kinds of problems yourself, look at the text after `_OBJC_CLASS_$_` and

- If that is one of the classes in your source tree, you have failed to add the implementation file to an Xcode target.
- If it's not then Google it to find which library/framework it belongs to, and that is the library/framework you are failing to link against.

Comment: Thank you save my day. I just link UIKit.framework again and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the file which you have imported. Can you please check whether you have imported .h file or .m file in your class?

This error is shown mainly in two situations :-

1. When you import .m file of some other class in your current class
   instead of .h file
2. When you add .h file to your target's Compile sources instead of .m file

Comment: No it's not as they are classes from `UIKit.framework`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Actually I have faced the same issue when I have done the above mistakes. In my case also all the frameworks where added to the target. The issue was I imported .m instead of .h

Comment: Well it depends on what classes are missing, as explained in my answer.

Comment: my Xcode not find arm7 and arm6 how solve this on bug for Xcode e