# Unity - using Fabric causes problems with iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

We're using Fabric with Crashlytics in our Unity Game and after building the iOS project with Unity and starting in Xcode we get about 26 errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABNetworkResponseHandler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABCertificatePinner", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
  "_FABGenerateUUID", referenced from:
      -[CLSAnalyticsIdentifierGenerator generateSessionFragmentIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsIdentifierGenerator.o)
      -[CLSAnalyticsIdentifierGenerator generateEventIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsIdentifierGenerator.o)
  "_FABApplicationShouldReportDeviceIdentifiers", referenced from:
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController identifierForAdvertising] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABHostGetOSVersion", referenced from:
      _CLSHostGetNormalizedOSVersion in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
  "_FABApplicationInstallationSource", referenced from:
      +[CLSBetaController isBetaSupported] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appInstallationSource] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
  "_CLSMachOFormatVersion", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageRecordMainExecutable in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_FABHostGetNormalizedOSVersion", referenced from:
      _CLSBetaToken in Crashlytics(CLSBetaToken.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABURLBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSReportsController.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetShortBundleVersion", referenced from:
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appDisplayVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController bundleShortVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABNetworkClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSReportsController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
  "_FABNetworkMaximumRetryCount", referenced from:
      ___51-[CLSBetaController loadUpdateWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient transmitLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:completionHandler:] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLSURLSessionConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLSUserDefaults", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsController.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetBundleVersion", referenced from:
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appBuildVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController bundleVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABEnumerateByteRangesOfNSDataUsingBlock", referenced from:
      -[CLSPackageReportOperation compressData:toPath:] in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetName", referenced from:
      -[CLSBetaUpdate promptMessage] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaUpdate.o)
  "_FABSettingsAvailableNotification", referenced from:
      -[CLSAnalyticsController initWithSessionIdentifier:sessionTimestamp:analyticsRootDirectoryWithURL:betaToken:identifierGenerator:timestampGenerator:metadataController:networkingClient:] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsController.o)
      -[CLSBetaController start] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetBundleIdentifier", referenced from:
      ___30-[Answers startWithBetaToken:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Answers.o)
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appBundleIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSCrashReportingController bundleIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
      -[CLSFileManager pathNamespace] in Crashlytics(CLSFileManager.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController bundleIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABHostOSBuildVersion", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController hostOSVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABHostModelInfo", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController hostModel] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController hostMachine] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABHostOSDisplayVersion", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
      +[CLSAnalyticsMetadataController hostOSVersionName] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsMetadataController.o)
  "_FABBuiltinCertificates", referenced from:
      +[CLSBetaController pinnnedCertificates] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      +[CLSNetworkClient pinner] in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how we can fix that issue? I checked the files in Unity and it seems everything is imported fine.

Comment: Could be any number of things. I'd start with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7/10170293

Comment: Checked the 'Link Binary With Libraries' as well as the 'Build Phases' and some other solutions suggested there, but didn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it somehow through reimporting the whole Fabric SDK in Unity - so deleting all files regarding Fabric and Crashlytics in the project and then importing Fabric again.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issues.