# Undefined symbols Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

After downloading Xcode 8 and migrating to Swift 3 I'm not longer able to archive the project. At the same time the project builds without any issues.

Error that I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.(subscript.materializeForSet :
>   (Swift.Int) -> A).(closure #1)", referenced from:
>         function signature specialization  of generic specialization
>   
>   with
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.MutableCollection in Swift and
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.RandomAccessCollection in Swift> of Swift._siftDown  (inout A,
>   index : A.Index, subRange : Swift.Range, by : inout
>   (A.Iterator.Element, A.Iterator.Element) -> Swift.Bool) -> () in
>   OrderCoordinator.o
>         function signature specialization  of generic specialization
>   
>   with
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.MutableCollection in Swift and
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.RandomAccessCollection in Swift> of Swift._heapSort  (inout A,
>   subRange : Swift.Range, by : inout (A.Iterator.Element,
>   A.Iterator.Element) -> Swift.Bool) -> () in OrderCoordinator.o
>         function signature specialization  of generic specialization
>   
>   with
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.MutableCollection in Swift and
>   Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer :
>   Swift.RandomAccessCollection in Swift> of Swift._partition  (inout A,
>   subRange : Swift.Range, by : inout (A.Iterator.Element,
>   A.Iterator.Element) -> Swift.Bool) -> A.Index in OrderCoordinator.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I was able to get rid of error by commenting array sorting code in following function:

```
func didFinishWithResults(_ results: [PhotoProcessorResult]) {
    guard let album = albumService.currentAlbum else { return }
    //let sortedResults = results.sorted(by: { $0.fileIndex < $1.fileIndex })
    let updateItems = zip(sortedResults, album.assetItems).map { (photoProcessorResult, assetItem) -> UpdateItem in
        UpdateItem(path: photoProcessorResult.filePath, position: photoProcessorResult.fileIndex, isCover: assetItem.isCover)
    }
    albumService.updateAlbumWithItems(updateItems) { (success, errorDescription) in
        if success {
            self.handleAlbumUpdate()
        } else {
            self.showFailureAlert(errorDescription) {
                self.startProcessingAlbum(self.albumService.currentAlbum)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While I resolved issue by sorting data using NSArray, I don't like this solution.

Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Post your code before change also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue disappeared after updating to XCode 8.1.
Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

Since it compiles i don't think there is anything wrong with your code.  The fact that it says "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" and is failing to archive tells me that something is going on with your project, but unfortunately there are many ways to cause this problem. arm7 is iphone 5 so your project is probably setup correctly only for arm64.  Try the solutions mentioned here: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 1):

If here is problem only for the this line:

```
let sortedResults = results.sorted(by: { $0.fileIndex < $1.fileIndex })
```

You can change to it:

```
let sortedResults = results.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return first.fileIndex < second.fileIndex
}
```

Did it solve your problem?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this didn't work for me. Nor did plain `array.sort()` (mine is just an array of `Float`s)