# Undefined symbol for architecture armv7 : "_NetworkRequestErrorDomain"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing this issue of  Undefined symbol for architecture armv7

```
:"_NetworkRequestErrorDomain", referenced from: 
 -[HSASIFormDataRequest addFile:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:] in HSASIFormDataRequest.o
      +[HSASIDataDecompressor uncompressDataFromFile:toFile:error:] in HSASIDataDecompressor.o
      +[HSASIDataDecompressor inflateErrorWithCode:] in HSASIDataDecompressor.o
      +[HSASIDataCompressor compressDataFromFile:toFile:error:] in HSASIDataCompressor.o
      +[HSASIDataCompressor deflateErrorWithCode:] in HSASIDataCompressor.o
```

This code was originaly developed with worklight.
I am using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Refereed all the links ... on stack..
Unable to find it

Comment: I don't understand what is the relation to IBM MobileFirst here. Please clarify what is this HSASI and what you're doing, where the failure is, etc

Comment: This project is created from IBM Worklight HSASI is some framework use here. while running or building the project it throws error..

Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue it gets resolved. HSASI framework was having issue I replace it with ASI Framework ..

Thanks For the help...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround with this issue was replacing the HSASI framework with the ASI Framework.