# ios – Xcode Errors Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 -MIsnap

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

We have an iOS app which uses MISNAP SDK version (2.3) as part of scanning functionality and it was working fine. Since the recent update came for MiSnap which is of version 3.0 and we wanted to update the library in our said application. We followed the docs and we replaced the necessary libraries and we are stuck with below errors even after multiple tries of resolving it.

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MiSnapViewController", referenced from: objc-class-ref
>
> in DCVC.o objc-class-ref in CCVC.o ld:
>
> symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

We dug up in internet searching solution for this issue and came along with **[this post](http://hailey.pomogi-mne.com/ios-xcode-errors-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-stack-overflow-4488016367/)** but we did not find any solution for the above error. We also created a sample project with the new version of the SDK and it works well. We doubt that this might be some configuration issue which we are unable to figure even after multiple tries.

Below is the current configuration for our application

**Deployment Target** - 7.1 and above

**Base SDK** - latest(9.0)

**Build Active architecture only** - Yes

**Valid architectures** - armv7 armv7s arm64

Comment: set Build Active architecture only to NO

Comment: I tried But no luck bro

Comment: in apple LLVM section, what is your optimization level?

Comment: @Saeed-rz Optimization Level is set to NONE

Comment: did you check this so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?rq=1